# Rewire switched outlet for ceiling fan

Tags: electrical

[image]
I know a similar question has been asked but mine is a bit different and confusing.

- I have a basic 14/2 wire coming from a switch going into an outlet box.
- The white from the switch is pigtailed with two other black wires, one from the power source, the other I believe is feeding other recepticles.
- The black from the switch goes into the outlet box as well to the top brass screw on the outlet itself (the bridge tabs on the outlet are not broken).
- There is a white wire going to the bottom silver screw, it's black wire is pigtailed with the other black wire and white switch wire.
- There is no black wire on the other side of this white wire on the outlet.
- The top silver screw also has a white wire and it's black wire is pigtailed with the other black and white switch wire.

I wanted to add a ceiling fan so I was able to run a 14/2 wire from the ceiling fan box I installed to the outlet box (wasn't able to run to the switch because of joist direction, etc). Is there a way to wire this up so the ceiling fan can be switched and the outlet is always hot?

Comment: The drawing is a good start. Please [edit] to include actual photos of the wiring in all the boxes involved (do _NOT_ disconnect any connected wires, especially it it is currently working) - just show us what's connected to what. Identify which cables are which and where they run to/from. I'm sure you'll get a good answer quickly that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is confusing and photos would probably help but that sounds like a basic switch loop: the black (hot) from the panel enters the outlet box and is connected to the white going to the switch (which should be marked black with tape or paint near the end but often isn't). The black back from the switch (switched hot) is connected to the outlet, along with the incoming white (neutral ) from the panel.

There may also be blacks and whites coming off the black and white from the panel to go to other unswitched outlets.

To make the outlet always hot, disconnect the black (coming from the switch) from the outlet and replace it with a pigtail connected to the (from panel) black.

To run switched power to the fan, connect the fan's black to the black from the switch an connect the fan's white to the white to the outlet (add a pigtail if necessary).

I've ignored grounds above - connect the fan ground to the other grounds.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added a picture to hopefully help. The ceiling fan/light at the top is currently not connected but in the outlet box. The two sets of wires that trail off to nothing, one is power, the other is feeding other outlets. Dotted lines are white wire.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much